# ¿Como agrupar este tipo de consulta?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo problemas al **formular la consulta** que me resuelva lo siguiente. Tengo una tabla como por ejemplo (ilustración). Necesito agrupar por el trío de columnas que aparecen en amarillo y la cuarta columna del resultado de la consulta seria el registro que primero aparece.

[image: ejemplo tabla origen]

... y necesito ver el resultado de la siguiente manera...

[image: resultado ejemplo de la consulta]

Comment: puedes modificar tu consulta? no se entiende bien lo que quieres

Comment: Lo que logre entender es que usted quiere como resultado de su consulta el valor de Concepto y necesita que los valores de esos campos NIT, FACTURA Y PACIENTE sean los mismos?

Comment: asi es, no quiero esos campos NIT, FACTURA Y PACIENTE repetidos, y ademas agregar el concepto (pero que sea el primero que aparezca)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando se usa [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT), la consulta toma al primero:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("NIT", "FACTURA", "PACIENTE")
       "NIT", "FACTURA", "PACIENTE", "CONCEPTO"
  FROM tabla;
```

[Ejemplo en rextester.com](http://rextester.com/RSVE31402)

Comment: pero y la columna CONCEPTO como la pongo?

Comment: Ahí está mostrando `*` (todas las columnas). En vez del `*` se puede seleccionar una lista de campos

Comment: Editado! no conocia esa herramienta, gracias!

Comment: Muy bueno. Años usando postgresql y no conocía "distinct on". Festejé cuando aparecieron las "window functions" donde se podía hacer esto en un solo select (y algunas cosas más). Y distinct on está hace años.

Answer (score 1):

Si es como lo explicas en la imagen, ya que no das mas datos, sería algo como:

```
SELECT nit,factura,cliente FROM tu_tabla WHERE concepto = 'AAA'
```

Comment: hola Andrés, gracias por responder, los datos que pongo son solo como ejemplo, no se trata de buscar el tipo de concepto "AAAA" la idea es agrupar ese trio de columnas que aparece en amarillo y la 4 sera la primera que aparezca

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TablaAgrupada AS 
(
SELECT  
      TABLA.NIT, TABLA.FACTURA, TABLA.PACIENTE,
      TABLA.CONCEPTO,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TABLA.NIT, TABLA.FACTURA, TABLA.PACIENTE ORDER BY TABLA.NIT ASC) AS RowNumber
FROM
    TABLA 
GROUP BY
    TABLA.NIT, TABLA.FACTURA, TABLA.PACIENTE, TABLA.CONCEPTO
)
SELECT  NIT,FACTURA,PACIENTE,CONCEPTO
FROM    TablaAgrupada
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
```

Prueba de esta manera, cualquier duda o sugerencía comenta. 
Slds...